# Find the child nodes in a graph using boost

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph

I am new to boost library. Is there any way to find all the child nodes of a graph using boost. Or any document which I can refer to for implementing this would be helpful. I thought of using Out_Edge Iterator because no out edge implies child node.

Comment: Do you visit this page http://www.ce.unipr.it/~medici/boost_ptree.html?

Comment: Is there any way without the use of ptree ? Just curious.

Comment: @H.H that's completely unrelated. I can address this layer tonight. It's really simple. However it would be helpful if OP could show some of the existing code

Comment: @H.H That's not for general purpose graphs (just trees), and doesn't allow any graph algorithms. I just posted an answer, but on re-reading the question I think Bad_Coder may have been asking about **leaf** nodes.

Comment: I'll add something about that now. Suffice it to say that leaf nodes have an out-degree of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On first reading I understood your question literally. Only on second reading I suspected you actually meant to look for *leaf nodes*.

### Finding Child Nodes

The question makes sense if you have a given node (say, vertex #5) and want to list the nodes that are reachable using 1 arc (edge).

Given a graph:

```
boost::adjacency_list<> g(10);
```

You get the vertex-descriptors of all the children of vertex 5:

```
for (auto vd : boost::make_iterator_range(adjacent_vertices(5, g)))
{
    std::cout << "vertex " << vd << " is an out-edge of vertex 5\n";
}
```

### Live Demo

To make things a little bit more interesting, let's generate a random graph:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce1bab1c3890d745)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/random.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main() {
    boost::adjacency_list<> g;
    std::mt19937 rng { 42 };

    generate_random_graph(g, 10, 20, rng);

    for (auto vd : boost::make_iterator_range(adjacent_vertices(5, g)))
    {
        std::cout << "vertex " << vd << " is an out-edge of vertex 5\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
vertex 1 is an out-edge of vertex 5
vertex 6 is an out-edge of vertex 5
```

And the graph is [visualized](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/100f919e157afbcd) as:

[image]

### Finding <strike>Nemo</strike> Lead Nodes

The number of edges connecting a vertex is called its *degree*. The number of outgoing edges can be queried with *`out_degree`*:

```
for (auto vd : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g)))
    std::cout << "vertex #" << vd << " has out_degree: " << out_degree(vd, g) << "\n";
```

You'll see that this means that vertices #1 and #2 are leaf nodes.

### BONUS:

Visualizing leaf nodes: [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06d09ea855f5d27d)

[image]

Comment: Added the alternative answer in case the question was about finding _leaf_ nodes instead.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Just curious to know if it is possible to use out_degree function and then check if its returning zero, then the node is a child node.

Comment: Didn't I just say that **and** show the code (and in the mean time used _exactly_ that to visualize it too). Note that in undirected graphs you'd need to use `degree(vd, g) == 1` or similar.

Comment: I'm just too fast :)

Comment: Sorry out of box question. Just want to know if you are running any classes on boost.

Comment: If you consider [SO] mentoring/tutoring running classes, then I've been for years. I also [live-streamed my activity on SO for (quite) a while](https://www.liveedu.tv/sehe) though LiveCoding.tv changed their terms of usage a bit too much and some material vanished. Other than that, no :)

Comment: Just adding to my question, a general one. Whenever i use a graph, the vertex always starts with 0, is there any way to remove vertex 0 ?

Comment: 0 is the vertex-descriptor. What you display is your choice. Just define the ID as `vertex_descriptor + 1`? Or use a vertex container that doesn't have an implicit vertex_index: [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2debdd9a4681e01) which visualizes to https://i.imgur.com/DPND6AT.png (note it is also undirected, and disallows duplicate edges)

Comment: And sometimes I'm so fast that I forget half the point: [Using labels](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf3d41b601ce004d) see https://i.imgur.com/AuQ5prZ.png

Comment: Thats a very good information. Boost is very interesting but what worries me sometimes is - if i have a graph like 1->2, 3->5, nodes 2,4 and 5 are considered leaf nodes but only 2 and 5 are leaf nodes. Is boost implemented that way to consider all the nodes ?

Comment: Boost doesn't "consider nodes leaf nodes". It tells you the degree. It's really an arbitrary definition to say whether unconnected nodes are leaves or not. Besides, my [simple adaptation of your sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce23e717a7c66134) shows otherwise https://i.imgur.com/meaBleA.png

Comment: If you insist, make the logic explicit: [for example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a060466ad5a9d25a) resulting in https://i.imgur.com/ZwMNIoI.png

Comment: By the way, "is boost implemented that way to consider all the nodes" - if you really meant "intermediate vertex ids not explicitly created", then you already have the answer since [18hrs ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608876/find-the-child-nodes-in-a-graph-using-boost/48611988#comment84221437_48611988)